# How to automatically import SwiftUI when importing a Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, package, swift-package-manager

**Context**

I created a custom `SwiftUI Package` which heavily relies on `SwiftUI`. When using this `Package` in my project, I always have to import `SwiftUI` and `MyCustomPackage` separately.
However, when importing `UIKit` or `SwiftUI`, the `Foundation Framework` gets imported Automatically. I would like to mimic this behaviour with my own `Package`.

---

**Code**

```swift
import SwiftUI // Automatically imports Foundation

---

import SwiftUI
import MyCustomPackage // I have to manually import SwiftUI next to MyCustomPackage
```

---

**Question**

- How can I achieve my goal to bundle `SwiftUI` with `MyCustomPackage`, so that I only have to explicitly import `MyCustomPackage`?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `@_implementationOnly` imports. Have look at this Swift forum thread and its replies: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-privatize-dependencies-in-swift-package-manager/33523

Comment: Also this link might give you some more recent efforts on import access control: https://forums.swift.org/t/pre-pitch-import-access-control-a-modest-proposal/50087 I assume all of this is still a work on progress for Swift and may not be something that you can use now, because underscored attributes are not officially supported and may change at any time or removed without warning. Using them in your library may negatively affect your clients.

Answer (score 1):

In the Sources folder for MyCustomPackage, create a file which should have this line of code:

`@_exported import SwiftUI`

Through this, when importing MyCustomPackage, it should now also auto import SwiftUI. Also within the package you won't need to import SwiftUI.

There are of course advantages and disadvantages of always importing a module as a dependency, as it may not be necessary